# Is there a way to add condition to cumsum without "cutting" my table?

Tags: python, pandas

I found the code to calculate a YTD (year to date) value (basically a **cumulative sum** applied to a **group by** function passed on "year").
But now, I want this cumulative sum only for when the "**Type**" column is "Actual" and not "Budget". I'd like to have either empty spaces for when `Type` = "Budget", or ideally, I'd like to have **332** (the last value of the YTD) displayed for all the rows where Type = "Budget.

**Initial table :**

```
     Value  Type   year  month
0     100  Actual  2018      1
1      50  Actual  2018      2
2      20  Actual  2018      3
3     123  Actual  2018      4
4      56  Actual  2018      5
5      76  Actual  2018      6
6      98  Actual  2018      7
7     126  Actual  2018      8
8      90  Actual  2018      9
9      80  Actual  2018     10
10     67  Actual  2018     11
11     87  Actual  2018     12
12    101  Actual  2019      1
13     98  Actual  2019      2
14     76  Actual  2019      3
15     57  Actual  2019      4
16     98  Budget  2019      5
17    109  Budget  2019      6
18    123  Budget  2019      7
19     67  Budget  2019      8
20     98  Budget  2019      9
21     67  Budget  2019     10
22     98  Budget  2019     11
23    123  Budget  2019     12
```

**This is the code that produced my actual table**

```
df['YTD'] = df.groupby('year')['Value'].cumsum()


     Value  Type   year    month YTD
0     100  Actual  2018      1   100
1      50  Actual  2018      2   150
2      20  Actual  2018      3   170
3     123  Actual  2018      4   293
4      56  Actual  2018      5   349
5      76  Actual  2018      6   425
6      98  Actual  2018      7   523
7     126  Actual  2018      8   649
8      90  Actual  2018      9   739
9      80  Actual  2018     10   819
10     67  Actual  2018     11   886
11     87  Actual  2018     12   973
12    101  Actual  2019      1   101
13     98  Actual  2019      2   199
14     76  Actual  2019      3   275
15     57  Actual  2019      4   332
16     98  Budget  2019      5   430
17    109  Budget  2019      6   539
18    123  Budget  2019      7   662
19     67  Budget  2019      8   729
20     98  Budget  2019      9   827
21     67  Budget  2019     10   894
22     98  Budget  2019     11   992
23    123  Budget  2019     12  1115
```

**Desired table :**

```
         Value  Type   year    month YTD
    0     100  Actual  2018      1   100
    1      50  Actual  2018      2   150
    2      20  Actual  2018      3   170
    3     123  Actual  2018      4   293
    4      56  Actual  2018      5   349
    5      76  Actual  2018      6   425
    6      98  Actual  2018      7   523
    7     126  Actual  2018      8   649
    8      90  Actual  2018      9   739
    9      80  Actual  2018     10   819
    10     67  Actual  2018     11   886
    11     87  Actual  2018     12   973
    12    101  Actual  2019      1   101
    13     98  Actual  2019      2   199
    14     76  Actual  2019      3   275
    15     57  Actual  2019      4   332
    16     98  Budget  2019      5   332
    17    109  Budget  2019      6   332
    18    123  Budget  2019      7   332
    19     67  Budget  2019      8   332
    20     98  Budget  2019      9   332
    21     67  Budget  2019     10   332
    22     98  Budget  2019     11   332
    23    123  Budget  2019     12   332
```

A solution that I found was simply to set a condition (where Type = "Actual"), but in this case the whole table wouldn't display, whereas I need to display it entirely...

Do you have an idea to overcome the partial selection problem ?

Thank you

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) we select only the rows where `Type = Actual` and we assign our `cumsum` to our new column `YTD`.

Then we fill our gaps of `NaN` with `GroupBy.ffill`:

```
m = df['Type'].eq('Actual')
df.loc[m, 'YTD'] = df.loc[m].groupby('year')['Value'].cumsum()
df['YTD'] = df.groupby('year')['YTD'].ffill()

    Value    Type  year  month    YTD
0     100  Actual  2018      1  100.0
1      50  Actual  2018      2  150.0
2      20  Actual  2018      3  170.0
3     123  Actual  2018      4  293.0
4      56  Actual  2018      5  349.0
5      76  Actual  2018      6  425.0
6      98  Actual  2018      7  523.0
7     126  Actual  2018      8  649.0
8      90  Actual  2018      9  739.0
9      80  Actual  2018     10  819.0
10     67  Actual  2018     11  886.0
11     87  Actual  2018     12  973.0
12    101  Actual  2019      1  101.0
13     98  Actual  2019      2  199.0
14     76  Actual  2019      3  275.0
15     57  Actual  2019      4  332.0
16     98  Budget  2019      5  332.0
17    109  Budget  2019      6  332.0
18    123  Budget  2019      7  332.0
19     67  Budget  2019      8  332.0
20     98  Budget  2019      9  332.0
21     67  Budget  2019     10  332.0
22     98  Budget  2019     11  332.0
23    123  Budget  2019     12  332.0
```